# Syntax error when using ImageDataGenerator class, flow method

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I am getting a syntax error in a seemingly straightforward line of code. can someone help with this issue? thank you.

```
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow(training_images,training_labels, batch_size=64)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

the previous cell where train_datagen was defined has run successfully.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                    rotation_range=40,
                    width_shift_range=0.2,
                    height_shift_range=0.2,
                    shear_range=0.2,
                    zoom_range=0.2,
                    horizontal_flip=True,
                    fill_mode='nearest'

    )
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Did you indent the code correctly in the cell? Are using tf.keras or just keras

Comment: There's no syntax error here. It must be higher up in your progam, like an unclosed parenthesis. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Indentation matters in python, I see the code is indented where it should not be.

Comment: I figured the issue and it is resolved now. I commented the ending parenthesis in the previous line by mistake. This caused the syntax error to appear in the current line. Apologies and thank you all.